How to manage FK between 2 tables?
I have a table whose fields are referenced by multiple tables. Now I needed to change the table, remove some columns, add new ones, change the order of the columns (purely for myself). But I cannot temporarily disable constraints and then enable them so that they already refer to the same fields of a new table. Doing this manually on each table seems very monotonous. Is there a way, using a loop or something else, to transfer foreign keys from one table to another? (In the new table, the column names for the refer remain the same). There is my tables:
table ItemsOld
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS market.items_old
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('market.items_id_seq'::regclass),
    card_id integer NOT NULL,
    article character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    update_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    is_prohibited boolean NOT NULL,
    link character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    category_id integer,
    category_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    mediafiles text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT items_article_key UNIQUE (article)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS market.items_old
    OWNER to postgres;

table ItemsNew
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS market.items
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('market.items_id_seq1'::regclass),
    uuid character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    card_id integer NOT NULL,
    article character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    category_id integer NOT NULL,
    category_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    brand character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    photos json,
    video character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    length double precision NOT NULL,
    width double precision NOT NULL,
    height double precision NOT NULL,
    link character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT items_pkey1 PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT items_article_key1 UNIQUE (article),
    CONSTRAINT items_item_uuid_key UNIQUE (item_uuid),
    CONSTRAINT items_link_key UNIQUE (link)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS market.items
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: items_id

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS market.items_id;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS items_id
    ON market.items USING btree
    (id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;


Check pg_constraint for all current foreign key constraints, write all the ALTER TABLE statements to drop the current foreign keys and write the ALTER TABLE statement to create the new foreign keys. And execute all these statements. This can be done in a loop, inside a function or DO statement
